# Statistics regarding count of images that my app handles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, sinatra

I've got a REST webservice created using sinatra. I'd like to get a count of number of images processed by my app, so I can use it for analytics purposes. How would one be able to do it?

What would be a way to do this i.e like a field on the DB? or Analytics like GA? or some other way?

Any opinion is apreciated

Comment: You should probably add some details of how/where in the app that the images are "processed". What does a count of 1 represent, and what part of the app is responsible for finalising that?

Comment: there are quite a few gems that act as `data-metric`s or `analytic`s. I have heard good things about [keen](https://github.com/keenlabs/keen-gem) and [fnordmetic](https://github.com/paulasmuth/fnordmetric). If you want Google Analytics there are a [massive amount of gems for that](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Web_Analytics)